# How to style the edges of a circular chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using fl_chart package, and it has been helpful, but it lacks the possibility to edit the circular chart styling to make the edges more circular, so if anyone could point out to a better way to achieve this design :

[image]

What I achieved so far

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CustomPainter

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProgressRings extends CustomPainter {
  /// From 0.0 to 1.0
  final double completedPercentage;
  final double circleWidth;
  final List<Color> gradient;
  final num gradientStartAngle;
  final num gradientEndAngle;
  final double progressStartAngle;
  final double lengthToRemove;

  ProgressRings({
    this.completedPercentage,
    this.circleWidth,
    this.gradient,
    this.gradientStartAngle = 3 * pi / 2,
    this.gradientEndAngle = 4 * pi / 2,
    this.progressStartAngle = 0,
    this.lengthToRemove = 0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    double radius = min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    double arcAngle = 2 * pi * (completedPercentage);

    Rect boundingSquare = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius);

    paint(List<Color> colors,
        {double startAngle = 0.0, double endAngle = pi * 2}) {
      final Gradient gradient = SweepGradient(
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        colors: colors,
      );

      return Paint()
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = circleWidth
        ..shader = gradient.createShader(boundingSquare);
    }

    canvas.drawArc(
      boundingSquare,
      -pi / 2 + progressStartAngle,
      arcAngle - lengthToRemove,
      false,
      paint(
        gradient,
        startAngle: gradientStartAngle,
        endAngle: gradientEndAngle,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter painter) => true;
}
```

Full Source [here](https://github.com/happyharis/neumorphic/blob/master/lib/neumorphic_pie/progress_rings.dart)

Video Link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGS-qVUCByQ)